# why the scala programe created by singleton object doesnt require a static main method?

Tags: scala, static, jvm, program-entry-point

I am new to scala ,and worked with java previosly.On studying i found that we can create a singleton object like given below

```
object Hello{
    def main(a:Array[String]){
        println("hello user")
    }
}
```

**If Scala uses JVM then why the scala programe created by singleton object doesnt require a static main method?**

I know its a very basic question but i am a beginner.
and also if anybody can suggest me some docs online to study scala.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala: defining main method that can be used by 'java'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737714/scala-defining-main-method-that-can-be-used-by-java)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Methods of singleton objects get translated into static methods (among other stuff)strong text. So you actually do have the equivalent of a static main method.

Have a look at the generated class files and you will see.