# How do I set up Scala plugin for NetBeans to copy the Scala runtime library?

Tags: netbeans, scala, ant, netbeans6.8

Versions: NetBeans 6.8, Scala Kit 0.16.1

When I compile my project, I get the following output:

```
init:
deps-jar:
Compiling 2 source files to F:\MyProgramming\NorvigSpellChecker\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: F:\MyProgramming\NorvigSpellChecker\dist
Building jar: F:\MyProgramming\NorvigSpellChecker\dist\NorvigSpellChecker.jar
Not copying the libraries.
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "F:\MyProgramming\NorvigSpellChecker\dist\NorvigSpellChecker.jar"

jar:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 3 seconds)
```

Of course, the libraries [should be copied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809138/creating-a-jar-file-from-a-scala-file), so I can't actually run it by using this command line. I don't see any options to copy the library in the project configuration.

The plugin uses Ant for building, but I don't have any experience with it; presumably it should be easy enough to tell Ant to copy the libraries. Here is [build-impl.xml](http://gist.github.com/355348), what should I do in build.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always copy scala-library.jar by hand (if Scala is not installed on the machine I'm running the project on), and run with

```
java -cp path/to/scala-library.jar:other/path/to/NBProject.jar NBProject
```

This isn't exactly an answer to your question if you're after a single jar to deploy and run, but it might be a useful workaround temporarily.

(By the way, think Windows uses `;` instead of `:` for the classpath separator.  Also, if you use Swing, you'll also need scala-swing.jar copied somewhere you can find it, and in the classpath.)