# How can I create a jar from some Scala source code?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, jar, clojure, interop

How can I create a jar from some Scala source code?  I want to use some of that code in a Clojure project of mine.

Is there a simpler way than doing batch files as in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809138/creating-a-jar-file-from-a-scala-file)?

Thanks,
Alex

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Scala is in no way special when it comes to what you do with the `.class` files produced by its compiler. Just use the `jar` command with the `c` action flag.

However, you will need to have the `scala-library.jar` file in the class-path when you run the program that uses the Scala-compiled `.class` files. And be careful to use the `scala-library.jar` for / from the same Scala Development Kit that you used to compile the Scala source. As of yet, there isn't inter-version binary compatibility for Scala-generated `.class` files.

Comment: so if I have a .class file I am fine?

Comment: Sure. And if you've got a directory (hierarchy) full of `.class` files from Scala, you can also just put its base name in the class-path. They really are not special from the perspective of other JVM code.

Comment: I'm having trouble getting my Intellij Clojure project to find the .class file I copied from my Scala project.  I wonder if it is because I don't seem to be able to find ANY .class files in the Clojure project. Clojure seems to be doing some kind of magic.

Comment: @Alex: Are you sure you properly respected the packages structure when copying `.class` files? Even though Scala doesn't care about directory / package correspondence (nor about file-name / class-name correspondence), the JVM insists that the directory hierarchy (of "loose" `.class` files or of JAR file contents) correspond precisely to the package structure of your `.class` files.

Answer (score 4):

One way in which creating .jar can be "simpler" is to use [simple-build-tool](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/Setup), which supports the [package*](http://code.google.com/p/simple-build-tool/wiki/RunningSbt) targets and requires rather little time to set up and use.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [maven scala plugin](http://scala-tools.org/mvnsites/maven-scala-plugin/) or the [buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/) tool.

Answer (score 1):

This has actually really helped

> If you are using eclipse then just export your project as a jar file
>
> goto file -> Export ->java -> as a jar file

Just bit more explanation:

1. Install the scala eclipse environment from [typesafe](http://scala-ide.org/)
2. Once you are done coding, export as a jar (file -> Export ->java -> as a jar file)
3. from a command line you can run java -cp path_to_dependancies:your_newly_generated_jar:. your_main_object_name.

hth.