# Launch a Scala Swing app on Windows without command window

Tags: java, windows, swing, scala, jar

I have a Swing app written in Scala in a `.jar` file. I made a desktop shortcut with the command `scala "filepath\filename.jar"` which works, except it brings up a command window first which sits in the background until I close the application. I want to make this go away.

I believe for Java you're supposed to use `javaw` instead of `java` for this purpose. I tried copying the `scala.bat` file to a new file called `scalaw.bat` to and changing line 24 to

```
if exist "%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe" set "_JAVACMD=%JAVA_HOME%\bin\javaw.exe"
```

and line 28 to

```
if "%_JAVACMD%"=="" set _JAVACMD=javaw
```

but (after updating the desktop shortcut) I'm still getting the command window coming up. Any ideas?

---

**Update**: I tried adding `scala-library.jar` to the manifest but it doesn't work, I guess because paths are relative to the jar's root. Other option seems to be include the whole scala-library jar within the jar file [(Creating a jar file from a Scala file)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/809138/creating-a-jar-file-from-a-scala-file), but I don't consider that a solution.

Or I can unpack the jar to its constituent `.class` files and use the shortcut

`javaw.exe -cp "%SCALA_HOME%/lib/scala-library.jar";"filepath\\" packageName.className`

but ... that involves unpacking the jar.

Another semi-workaround Ive found is to edit the shortcut so that it the command window runs minimized.

---

**Solution**: as per eugener's answer, you need to use `javaw` *without* the -jar option, but specifying the jar-file e.g.

```
javaw -cp "%SCALA_HOME%/lib/*";"C:/path/yourjar.jar" packageName.className
```

If it's a Swing app and you use the `scala-swing` library you'll need to include that as well, or use the `*` wildcard as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would advise to **launch your app directly using javaw**. Since Scala compiles into the same byte code as Java - you can do it. Don't forget to add standard scala libraries to the class path

Comment: But if you're launching a `jar` the classpath has to already be in the manifest?

Comment: You can either use the manifest or can describe you class path using -cp parameter, which is more flexible IMO

Comment: If you use both -cp and -jar, then the -cp settings are ignored

Comment: Launch from a shortcut, make the shortcut point to javaw.exe, and the args point to your jar, classpath, etc.

Comment: @Kevin, that doesn't work because to launch a jar file with javaw you need to use the `-jar` option, in which case you can't specify a classpath for your scala library

Comment: no... you have to launch as normal java program,  without -jar arg, by specifying main class and full class path, including scala-library.jar

Comment: OK, gotcha, it's working now, thanks. Very tricky to get everything exactly right. +1

Answer (score 1):

It's clearly stated in the [`java` command explanation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html), about `-jar`:

> When you use this option, the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Making a shortcut with
javaw.exe -cp "%SCALA_HOME%\lib\scala-library.jar";"%SCALA_HOME%\lib\scala-swing.jar";"C:/path/yourjar.jar" packageName.mainClassName
did work.

The solution is hence include libraries + packaged target code with `-cp` argument and don't use  the `-jar` switch. As also given as a solution in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to compile your `bat` file to `exe` (I used `quick batch file compiler`). I believe this prevent command window appearance. I did not use Windows for a long time, but I remember it helped me sometimes.