# How to compile java or scala code into jar in an activity in Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I'm fetching arbitrary scala code to execute in an activity and in another activity I want to execute this. [This link](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/data-factory-map-reduce/) describes how to execute via jar. So I need to compile the fetched scala code or run the code directly. Any help appreciated

Comment: I found below post will be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/809138/creating-a-jar-file-from-a-scala-file